# How do I select these nested tags with jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I find theses two examples using the same code.

```
<div>
  <div>
    <span class='example-1'></span>
  </div>
  <ul class='find-me'> <!-- find this for example 1 -->

    <li>
      <span></span>
      <ul class='find-me'></ul>
    </li>

    <!-- Any number of li tags here -->

    <li>
      <span class='example-2'></span>
      <ul class='find-me'></ul>  <!-- find this for example 2 -->
    </li>

    <!-- Any number of li tags here -->

  </ul>
</div>
```

Given that I have the jQuery object for for example-1 and example-2, how do I write an identical selector for both examples? Is it possible?

I can't just do selector.parent().find(".find-me") because this won't work for the first example.
I can't do selector.parent().parent().find(".find-me:first") because this will select the wrong find-me in the second example.

I need to somehow say go up to the grandparent then go to where you started and find the next find-me class.

**Edit: The answers so far all seem to be misunderstanding.  There must be only one selector that works for both examples, and the selector must be relative to the jQuery object that represents the example span.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the best that I can come up with:

```
var $example1 = $(".example-1");
var $example2 = $(".example-2");

$example1.add($example1.parents()).siblings('.find-me').css("color", "red");
$example2.add($example2.parents()).siblings('.find-me').css("color", "blue");​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HNfpM/3/**

Comment: I can't see how that would work, the second example will select the .find-me above the example rather than below it. http://jsfiddle.net/HNfpM/

Comment: Why do you need to do this? It will be easier to change your markup rather than coming up with a convoluted jQuery selector.

Comment: The real use case is more complex - and flexible, and needs to be abstracted as this simpler example demonstrates.  I've given you a consolation upvote for at least understanding the question. No one else seems to have done so.

Comment: @SystemicPlural: It might be possible to construct a selector, but it shouldn't require this much effort. Your two elements are in different places relative to the initial elements. Consider restructuring your HTML.

Comment: @SystemicPlural: Here's the neatest selector that I could hack together: http://jsfiddle.net/HNfpM/2/. It works for arbitrary levels of nesting, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Great, thanks, that works. It adds the necessary dom elements without loosing the location of the selector. I've modified it slightly so that it only adds the current parent rather than the whole DOM. http://jsfiddle.net/HNfpM/3/ If you amend your answer, I'll mark it correct. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.find-me')[0]` for first example
`$('.find-me')[2]` for second example

Comment: I need to use an identical selector for moth cases. And it needs to be relative to the selected jquery example element

Answer (score 0):

How about `$("div span, li span")` or you can use css3 selector:[att^=val]  http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/
I would use css3 selector actually. I've added a working demo on the comment

Comment: I need to use an identical selector for both cases. And it needs to be relative to the selected jquery example element

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div > ul.find-me'); <!-- find this for example 1 -->
```

```
$('div > ul > li > ul.find-me'); <!-- find this for example 2 -->
```

Comment: I need to use an identical selector for both cases. And it needs to be relative to the selected jquery example element